# Error when opening VS2008 solution on VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I get the below error whne trying to open a .sln. The project was created in VS2008 but I am trying to open it on 2010. I have administrator rights and have reset the IIS.

“Error: One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly”.
The output window says : "The project type is not supported by this installation".

Is there a work around for this or do I need to go back to VS2008?

```
Activity log shows this error:
<entry>
             <record>136</record>
             <time>2004/02/26 00:42:59.706</time>
             <type>Error</type>
             <source>Microsoft Visual Studio</source>
             <description>Loading UI library</description>
             <guid>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</guid>
             <hr>800a006f</hr>
             <path></path>
         </entry>
```

Comment: What's the project type?

Comment: While it's fairly obvious to guess, can you confirm in which version of VS the solution file was created, and in which version you are trying to open it? Your first sentence mentions that it was both created and opened in VS2008, yet your title and tags include VS2010.

Comment: it's a C# form application. I'm not sure if this is notable, but I unchecked Read-Only, but it keeps turning back into Read-Only

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough :) It was created in VS2008 and I am trying to open in 2010

Comment: Can you check the log and specify which project type couldn't be loaded?

Comment: @MikeCheel 1. Smart Device (C#) ProjectTypeGuids{4D628B5B-2FBC-4AA6-8C16-197242AEB884} 2. Windows (C#) ProjectTypeGuids{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}

Comment: It sounds like a device emulator. You might have to manually upgrade that part of the project to the new version of the project template if there is one.

Comment: Smart device projects are no longer supported in VS2010.  They were hit by a giant apple.  There's something seriously wrong with the clock on your machine btw, the year 2004 was a while ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments it appears that the project that isn't loading is a smart device project. According to this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32d20366-5421-48de-8fef-68c215f2f395/how-to-convert-smart-device-project-to-visual-studio-2010

> VS2010 doesn't support WM6.x and WM5.0 OS development, it only support
>   Windows Phone 7.0. So the conversion fails. We have to use vs2005/2008
>   to develop WM6.x and WM5.0 projects. VS2008/2005 doesn't support
>   Windows Phone 7.0, only vs2010 support it.

So it appears you will have to continue to support this app in VS2008 or upgrade it to support the newer phone platform.